# Something wrong with my conda channel and leads to a tensorflow import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conda

I created a Conda environment with `python 3.6` and `venv` and activated it. then installed `tensorflow` with

```
pip install tensorflow
```

However, there is something wrong with my python. Basically like when i run `python` i get:

```py
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  5 2017, 07:59:26) [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

but with `python3.6` everything works fine:

```py
Python 3.6.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr 24 2020, 16:44:11) [GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

I basically want to type the "python" into my command line and to work fine with tensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Something is really strange with the way you are doing this, you shouldn't need a venv on top of your environment and you should install tensorflow with a conda rather than a pip install (reason being conda is an environment manager and solves for all packages to work together, whereas pip may install or uninstall things in a way that messes up the whole environment solution; tldr, more likely to work). Try making a new environment and see how this works out

```
conda create -n tfenv tensorflow=2
```

if you instead want Python 3.6 (other one will use latest python that works with tensorflow, should be 3.7)

```
conda create -n tfenv python=3.6 tensorflow=2
```

then, as usual activate the environment with

```
conda activate tfenv
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answering. I tried this however it install the tensorflow with version 1.13. Is there something I can do to work fine with tf2.2 (latest one)?

Comment: @Zhihua Strange, tf2 should be default (it is on mine), perhaps you need to update your conda with conda update conda and conda update anaconda. You can also ensure it will give you a tensorflow 2 using conda create -n tfenv tensorflow=2